# How can mysql db be restored in dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, apache2

I'm trying to restore MySQL DB to a ubuntu docker container which has Apache and MySQL services. Here's my docker file
FROM ubuntu

```
RUN apt-get update -y
ENV DATABASE_SERVER 'IP'
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y && apt-get install php7.4 -y && apt-get install mysql-server >
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/www/html/
COPY ./startup.sh /var/www/
COPY ./db_test.php /var/www/html
COPY ./my_sql_secure.sh /var/www/
COPY ./backup.sql /var/www/html/
RUN bash /var/www/my_sql_secure.sh
COPY ./restoredb.sh /var/www/
CMD bash /var/www/startup.sh
EXPOSE 80
```

Here's my startup.sh

```
apache2 -DFOREGROUND | service mysql start | mysql -uroot sentrifugo < /var/www/html/backup.sql
```

If I run startup.sh without "mysql -uroot sentrifugo < /var/www/html/backup.sql" , the script properly brings up mysql service but when I run with it doesn't run.

From what i know CMD accepts only two commands and running the restoredb.sh after startup.sh replaces it.
I just want to restore the mysql Database and run mysql and apache in foreground. I can't use docker-compose as per the requirement I have.

Could someone please tell me what can be done to achieve it.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You'd almost always run Apache and MySQL in separate containers.  You're not forced to use Docker Compose, you can have two separate `docker run` commands to launch the two containers.  `CMD` only accepts _one_ command.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what image you are building `FROM`, assuming that it is an official MySQL image, you just `COPY` your `backup.sql` into the seed folder:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions `.sh`, `.sql` and `.sql.gz` that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

(from the [MySQL page on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) )

So, change:

```
COPY ./backup.sql /var/www/html/
```

...to:

```
COPY ./backup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

If you are using a custom image, and it seems that you may be, the you might want to have an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) that executes that import script on startup.

Also, your `startup.sh` might work with some changes:

```sh
service mysql start && \
mysql -uroot sentrifugo < /var/www/html/backup.sql;
apache2 -DFOREGROUND
```

This will start the MySQL service first, then populate the DB. Then, finally, start up Apache.

One last thing, the preferred form of `CMD` is the *exec* form. This would have your `CMD` look like this:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash","/var/www/startup.sh"]
```

(ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD did the trick. Thanks once again